# AS3 how to access html text field with links inside 2 movieclips

Tags: html, actionscript-3, nested, textfield

I am a beginner and have been working since few days to get to this point. I would appreciate some help.

I have a properly formated HTML textfield(instance name: **myHTML**) nested inside 1 movieclip: **Symbol1** which is inturn nested in movieclip: **white_bg**
myHTML has links in it and needs to be inside these 2 movieclips because of animation.

I have one first empty frame this as3:

```
var myHTMLText:String = "<h1>new projects:</h1>"+
"<a href='http://www.somewebsite1.html'>somewebsite1</a> \n"+
"<a href='http://www.somewebsite2.html'>somewebsite2</a> \n"+
"<a href='http://www.somewebsite3.html'>somewebsite3</a>;

//create and initialize css
var myCSS:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
myCSS.setStyle("h1", {fontSize:'13',color:'#666666'});
myCSS.setStyle("a:link", {color:'#0099CC',textDecoration:'none'});
myCSS.setStyle("a:hover", {color:'#003366',textDecoration:'none'});
myHTML.styleSheet = myCSS;
myHTML.htmlText = myHTMLText;
```

I tested the movie but I get an error: "1120: Access of undefined property myHTML." i searched many Blogs. Too complicated. Is there a simple way to click/access this textfield within these clips?

Comment: Are you sure that you named the instance on the stage myHTML and didn't make that the Symbol/Class name?  Find the myHTML text on the stage select it and go to properties to confirm the instance name is set to myHTML.

Comment: Hi Husain, myHTML is the instance name given to it and its a Dynamic textfield inside movieclips.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly and your action script is on the root timeline it should be

> white_bg.Symbol1.myHTML.htmlText = myHTMLText;

Comment: Yes my as3 is in the first frame or root.
This code is not working. I tested it.
I changed `myHTML.htmlText = myHTMLText;` to
`white_bg.Symbol1.myHTML.htmlText = myHTMLText;`

Comment: This is the error: **1120: Access of undefined property white_bg.**

Comment: And as shaunhusain mentioned, have you checked that you have set the instance name for the object in the Properties panel?

Comment: I re-checked it. Yes it has the same instance name: myHTML

Actually it works perfect when I put the textfield onto the Stage and not inside movieclips.

Comment: Oh BTW I forgot to mention.. I am using CS4.

Comment: I think the best way to resolve this would be for you to post the .fla file somewhere so I can see what's going on.

Comment: Hi, i am happy already that I found the solution. It seems the code must be places inside the movieclip which holds it. Now its working :)